# Convert List(Of HtmlElement) to HtmlElementCollection class

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

Here is my code..

```
Private Function GetElement(ByVal hec As ICollection, ByVal strAttName As String, ByVal strAttVal As String) As List(Of HtmlElement)
    Dim hecFilter As New List(Of HtmlElement)
    Dim str As String
    For Each El As HtmlElement In hec
        str = El.GetAttribute(strAttName)
        If (Not IsNothing(str) AndAlso str.Trim() = strAttVal) Then
            hecFilter.Add(El)
        End If
    Next
    Return hecFilter
End Function
```

It would return me `List(Of HtmlElement)`

Now I want to convert it into `HtmlElementCollection` `class`.

Trying to do this

```
Private Function GetElement(ByVal hec As HtmlElementCollection, ByVal strAttName As String, ByVal strAttVal As String) As HtmlElementCollection
    Dim hecFilter As New List(Of HtmlElement)
    Dim str As String
    For Each El As HtmlElement In hec
        str = El.GetAttribute(strAttName)
        If (Not IsNothing(str) AndAlso str.Trim() = strAttVal) Then
            hecFilter.Add(El)
        End If
    Next
    Return TryCast(hecFilter, HtmlElementCollection)
End Function
```

It is showing an error:

> Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement)' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection'.

Comment: Try **hecFilter.Cast<HtmlElementCollection>()**

Comment: Tried `TryCast(hecFilter, HtmlElementCollection)` also

Answer (score 0):

`HtmlElementCollection` [implements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelementcollection.aspx) `ICollection` that [doesn't have](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.aspx) `Add()`, `IEnumerable` [doesn't have](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) it either..

I guess that constructor accepting  elements is `internal`. Thus threat this collection as read-only.

Comment: any solution or suggestion

Comment: @vikas: What for do you need return collection and not a list?

Comment: I want a function with return type `HtmlElementCollection` where `HtmlElementCollection` as parameter. I want to filter `HtmlElementCollection` actually

Comment: @vikas: you can filter `List<HtmlElementCollection>`, can't you? Or you want assign collection back?

Comment: how I can filter, I am using framework 2.0, it is there in 2.0?

Comment: @vikas: Write your own LINQ-like extension methods, that's easy.